# How do I put in a variable for an enom value?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, literals, codable

I am working on a sizable app with multiple API. One of those API, for some reason, one API is structured like this:

```
{
"KOMN" : [
{
"state" : string,
"state_full" : string,
"city" : string,
"volume" : string,
"airport_name" : string,
"military" : string,
"faa_ident" : string,
"icao_ident" : string,
"chart_seq" : string,
"chart_code" : string,
"chart_name" : string,
"pdf_name" : string,
"pdf_path" : string
},
{
"state" : string,
"state_full" : string,
"city" : string,
"volume" : string,
"airport_name" : string,
"military" : string,
"faa_ident" : string,
"icao_ident" : string,
"chart_seq" : string,
"chart_code" : string,
"chart_name" : string,
"pdf_name" : string,
"pdf_path" : string
},
...
]

And so on..
```

The whole outer dictionary contains one key that changes depending on the user query. I need a way to insert a variable in where the "KOMN" value in the enom coding key value is. Is there a way to do that? I have tried various string interpolations but get an error about the enom requiring a "literal" value. If I could substitute this value out with a variable I created, the data pull would be successful.

Here is my coddle:

```
struct ChartData: Codable {
    let dataPoints: [DataPoints]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case dataPoints = "KDAB"
    }
}

struct DataPoints: Codable {
    let state: String?
    let stateFull: String?
    let city: String?
    let volume: String?
    let airportName: String?
    let military: String?
    let faaIdent: String?
    let icaoIdent: String?
    let chartSeq, chartCode, chartName, pdfName: String?
    let pdfPath: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case state
        case stateFull = "state_full"
        case city, volume
        case airportName = "airport_name"
        case military
        case faaIdent = "faa_ident"
        case icaoIdent = "icao_ident"
        case chartSeq = "chart_seq"
        case chartCode = "chart_code"
        case chartName = "chart_name"
        case pdfName = "pdf_name"
        case pdfPath = "pdf_path"
    }
}
```

From what I understand, this is structured like:
Dictionary with one key "KOMN" (what I need to be able to substitute) > Array of Dictionaries. I tried ```
let importedChart = chartData?.dataPoints
let importedListingPdf1 = importedChart?[0].pdfPath
print(importedListingPdf1)

```
but got nil when I tried removing the keycoding = hard coded string value. Right now, the enom case dataPoints has to be equal to the search query, but again, I can't figure out how to pass that data in.

Help would be appreciated!
```

Comment: Why not decode it as a [String: [DataPoints]]?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I apologize, I'm pretty new to swift :)

Comment: What do you mean, when you decode it of course, `JSONDecoder().decode([String: [DataPoints]], from: data)`

Comment: How will that let me substitute my enom value?

Comment: ```let chartDeta = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String: [DataPoints]].self, from: chartData)``` and now I can't seem to pull my values from chartData

Comment: Don't use `try?`, instead use `try` with a `do{} catch {print(error)}`. What is the problem with extracting data, it's not clear from your comment? Another thing that is not clear is if the key, KOMN or KDAB or..., is important after the decoding is done?

Comment: That key is important because it accesses the entire dictionary with the information at the API. for some reason the API is set up to use the search query as the initial dictionary key, which makes it difficult to access because the enom will not let me put a variable in to access the dictionary.